# Generate e-mail with hidden fields which Exchange can categorize

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server, dynamically-generated

I'm generating an HTML e-mail and BCC'ing to a hard-coded address. In the receiving end I want an Outlook/Exchange rule to pick up that e-mail and place it in a specific folder, but there is *no visible field, subject or text* in the e-mail which I can use identify the rule.

I tried adding an `<input type="hidden" value="use_me_for_your_rule"/>` HTML element, but Outlook/Exchange didn't identify the `"use_me_for_your_rule"` string when I added a rule for it.

What is a good way to do this? (Note that the e-mail is totally configurable and translated (and re-translated) to 50 different markets, so adding (and updating) 50 different rules in Outlook is not a viable solution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found was to create a new mailbox - sigh.